# Comparing spaces in python

Tags: string, python-3.x

I am creating a cipher script in python without any modules but I have come accross a problem that i cant solve. When I am comparing msg[3] which has the value (space) it should be equal to bet[26] which is also a space. If i compare msg[3] with bet[26] in the shell...

```
>>>msg[3] == bet[26]
True
```

The output is True. However when i run the program and output the value of enmsg there is no value 26 where the value 26 should be.

```
enmsg = []
msg = "try harder"    
bet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "
for x in range(0, len(msg)):
    for i in range(0, 26):
        if msg[x] == bet[i]:
            print(msg[x])
            enmsg.append(i)
```

Comment: `max(range(0, 26)) == 25`.  `bet[25] == 'z'`.  You never check for spaces.  This is one of the reasons you should iterate directly over lists and strings, and not over their indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get out of the habit of iterating over a range of indices and then looking up the value at the index.  Instead iterate directly over your iterables, using `enumerate` when necessary.

```
enmsg = []
msg = "try harder"    
bet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "
for msg_char in msg:
    for index, bet_char in enumerate(bet):
        if msg_char == bet_char:
            print(msg_char)
            enmsg.append(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second loop iterations are too short so it is not reaching the space symbol.
Try with this:

```
enmsg = []
msg = "try harder"    
bet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "
for x in range(0, len(msg)):
    for i in range(len(bet)):
        if msg[x] == bet[i]:
            print(msg[x])
            enmsg.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

The upper bound of range is not inclusive; you'll need to extend this by one to actually check the 26th index of the string. Better yet, iterate up through `len(bet)` as you did for `len(msg)` for the outer loop.